# Microcontroller bit fields

Tags: struct, union, microcontroller, bit-fields

I am learning about microcontrollers and I am having difficulty understanding how one would use a union to set individual bits on a gpio port.

```
typedef union _BYTE
{
    byte _byte;
    struct
    {
        unsigned b0:1;
        unsigned b1:1;
        unsigned b2:1;
        unsigned b3:1;
        unsigned b4:1;
        unsigned b5:1;
        unsigned b6:1;
        unsigned b7:1;
    }Bit;
} BYTE;
```

I am using the above to gain access to the individual bits of a byte, but how do I use this to assign a io port values in the following manner?

```
MCF_GPIO_PORTDD.Bit.b0 = 1;
```

I would rather not allocate a type of _BYTE and then assign the port to that.

```
#define MCF_GPIO_PORTDD             (*(vuint8 *)(&__IPSBAR[0x100009]))
```

MCF_GPIO_PORTDD is just a memory address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's casting the port pointer to a `volatile unsigned char` (8 bit int).  You can make a similar macro for your type:

```
#define PORTDD  (*(volatile BYTE *)(&__IPSBAR[0x100009]))
```

and then access it with `PORTDD.Bit.b0`.  Note that in some instances you will need to write `._byte` directly if you need to ensure multiple bits are set (or cleared) in a single register write.  If you don't name `Bit` (just make it anonymous) your C compiler may let you shorten that to `PORTDD.b0`.

Comment: This is called a `structure overlay`, to throw in some terminology.